# how to sync different .vue file

Tags: vue.js

i'm new with `vue.js`. i have two different `vue.js` file

this is the first file:

```
<template>
  <SecondFile />
</template>

<script>
import SecondFile from SecondFile.vue
export default {
  name: 'FirstFile',
  component : { SecondFile },
};
</script>
```

this first vue file contains a value with variable profile.status which bring the value (active / inactive ) and i wanna pass it to second vue file.

this is the second file:

```
<template>
<a-dropdown class="action-bar">
    <a class="action-dropdown" href="#"> ACTION <a-icon type="down" /> </a>
      <a-menu slot="overlay">
        <a-menu-item>
          <a href="javascript:;">EXPORT PDF</a>
        </a-menu-item>
        <a-menu-item>
          <a href="javascript:;">{{ profile.status }}</a>
        </a-menu-item>
        <a-menu-item>
          <a href="javascript:;" style="color:#b00606;">DELETE</a>
        </a-menu-item>
      </a-menu>
    </a-dropdown>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SecondFile',
};
</script>
```

the `profile.status` value does not appear in the second file. how can i pass the value of `profile.status`? anyone can help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few way to communicate between Vue components, one of them is using Props.

steps:

1. add props property in the second file:

```
    export default {
      name: 'SecondFile',
      props: {
        profile: Object      
      }
    };
```

2. edit first file:

```
    <template>
        <SecondFile :profile="profile"/>
    </template>
```

see:[Passing Data to Child Components with Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)